C#. Возможна ли перегрузка статических классов?
Я знаю, что у обычных классов перегрузка невозможна из-за непонятности к какому именно классу объект будет принадлежать. А со статическими(static) как? У них не может быть объектов. Я просто хотел бы добавить насколько методов к классу File (эти методы пока находятся в классе с другим именем).

Методы расширения.

@EvgeniyZ, кажется, они как раз для статических не получатся?

Стоило бы написать, что тут подразумевается под "перегрузкой классов".

@Qwertiy А я и не говорю, что они будут работать со статикой, просто кинул как напоминание того, что такая возможность есть, можно ведь сделать расширение в обратную сторону, условно "C:\File.txt".ReadAllLines();, все зависит от желания и требований... Ну а отвечая на вопрос, ответ будет скорей отрицательным, тут только делать свою обертку над классом, добавляя тем самым нужные методы (а-ля FileExt.ReadAllLines(...);).

@user7860670, в последнем предложении написано ведь: классу File добавить несколько методов.

если в следующей версии дотнета таки добавят extension type  - тогда можно будет расширить и статические классы и много чего ещё. А пока, к сожалению, FileHelper

Ну да, что такое "перегрузка классов"? Вот добавить насколько методов к классу File - это понятно.
Как уже подсказал @EvgeniyZ, можно использовать методы расширения, но таким образом нельзя расширить класс статическими методами.
using System;
static class SuperString {
    public static string Dyr(this string s) {
        return s.Substring(0,2);
    }
    public static bool IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(string s) {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
    }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("asdf".Dyr());
        Console.WriteLine(SuperString.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace("asdf"));
    }
}

Здесь Dyr - метод, расширяющий класс String.
Если подумать, то расширять класс статическими методами в существующих ограничениях смысла нет, так как мы не сможем получить доступ к приватным членам класса. Поэтому статические методы, использующие объекты нужного типа, могут быть созданы в любом классе. Как пример, метод IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace.
